# Does using eyeliner (Kohl) break the fast?

Tags: sharia, sawm, muftirat

Eyeliner eye(Kohl) is known from a long time and also in the time of the Prophet. All the people, whether they are men or women, put kohl on their eyes.

Does using eyeliner(Kohl) break the fast?

Answer (score 5):

Sources: [fatwa from islam Q&A](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/92923)

### Short answer:

most scholars agree that eyeliner will not break the fast, but it would be best to wear it at night, due to caution of the possiblity of it entering your body. Also, in the blessed month of ramadan, we are encourged to give up plesures that we usually enjoy outside of ramadan.

### Details

Shaykh Ibn Baaz (may Allaah have mercy on him) was asked in Majmoo’ al-Fataawa (15/260):

What is the ruling on women using kohl and some cosmetics during the day in Ramadaan? Do these things break the fast or not?

He replied:

Kohl does not break the fast of men or women according to the more correct of the two scholarly opinions, but it is better to use it at night if one is fasting.

The same applies to soaps, creams etc that are used to beautify the face and are applied to the surface of the skin, including henna, makeup and the like. There is nothing wrong with using them for one who is fasting, but makeup should not be used if it will cause harm to the face. And Allaah is the source of strength. End quote.

Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (may Allaah have mercy on him) was asked about the ruling on a fasting person using ointment to treat dryness of the lips.

He replied:

There is nothing wrong with a person using ointment to moisturise the lips or nose, or moistening them with water, or with a cloth and the like, but he should avoid anything that could reach the throat. But if anything reaches the throat without him intending it to, there is no sin on him, just as if he rinses his mouth and some water reaches his throat by accident, his fast is not invalidated by that. End quote.

Majmoo’ al-Fataawa (19/224).

Shaykh Ibn Jibreen (may Allaah preserve him) said in Fataawa ‘Ulama’ Balad al-Haraam (201):

There is nothing wrong with applying creams to the body when fasting if there is a need for that, because the cream only reaches the surface of the skin and does not enter the body. Even if it is absorbed by the pores it is not regarded as breaking the fast. End quote.

And Allaah knows best.